# How to use past simple instead of 'used to'?

Tags: tense, past-simple

I just noticed this use of past simple in Genesis 1:2:

> And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.

It says *moved upon the face of the waters* rather than *used to move upon the face of the waters*.

Past simple give to me the impression that it moved once, and that's it. But I don't think that's actually the meaning. I think it meant it was moving until something happened, is it correct?

How can I use more past simple like this?

Comment: I'm afraid you're misunderstanding *was* and *was used to*. The Spirit here is not a tool, like you might say, "The axe **was used to** chop down the tree." Simple past is correct here, and is often used in narratives.

Comment: Yes, maybe I incorrectly put the was. I'll edit the question. I'm thinking in sentences like: I used to live in England; I used to be a teacher; I used to move upon the face of the waters.

Comment: No worries. I'll look again when you edit it.

Comment: Moved here does not say when the movement started or ended. It also is not specific as to how much movement took place, just that it had an end and a beginning. If you look at the sentences, they are saying "and", which means "these things were happening at the same time" -- this event which had happened in the past. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is of course a translation, and a 400-year-old translation at that. [This](https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-2.htm) shows that more recent versions say _was hovering_. But the whole passage is a piece of description; we don't have to use _used to_  in every narrative set in the past.

Comment: The part starting with "spirit" may be a departure from the static background state described, and may mean the first action. If so, "was moving" wouldn't fit.